# How to use ActiveX(ocx) in java

Tags: java, ocx

I want to use the functions in an OCX , how to call it in JAVA? Please give me an example if possible. Thanks very much.

Comment: For what I understand, you need some kind of native COM bridge to achieve this. Have Google, I found http://www.ezjcom.com/ and I use [ComfyJ](http://www.teamdev.com/comfyj/)

Answer (score 10):

I think you must use COM bridge to use OCX in java.

1.[Java to COM and ActiveX 2-way bridge connectivity utility](http://java2com.com/)

2.[JACOB - Java COM Bridge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/)

3.[Java COM Bridge](http://javacombridge.com/)

4.[Java - COM Interoperability](http://sourceforge.net/projects/j-interop/)

Comment: In my experience, JACOB seems to be the most popular bridge.

Comment: EZ Jcom or JACOB Which is more preferable for a beginner like me? -Thanks in advance.